# Run a program on cmd right after compilation (Code Runner plugin on vscode)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I installed `Code Runner` to compile my C code.
I want the `.exe` will be directly opened on my cmd after compiling the program like the way Visual Studio is working.

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it mentions in the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Go to VS Code > Preferences:

- Then Type: Code Runner

[image: Code Runner]

You will see `Code-Runner: Executor-Map` click on **Edit in settings.json**, You'll see something like this:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false
}
```

Then add this below `"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false`, like this:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "nodejs",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && start $dir$fileName"
    }
}
```

And Congratulations :)